# Path Definition For Each Route in Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I would like to add a path to each route that I define in `spring.cloud.gateway.routes` without defining context path, `server.servlet.context-path`, of each microservice.

E.g.: My gateway runs at port 9090, and my microservice runs at port `8071`. The configuration for the microservice in the gateway is like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: auth
          uri: 'http://localhost:8071'
```

If I hit `http://localhost:9090/lorem/ipsum`, I can ping the microservice, and see the response. But, I would like to ping the microservice from the gateway as `http://localhost:9090/auth/lorem/ipsum`.

If I define `Path` key in `predicates`, it pings `http://localhost:8071/auth/lorem/ipsum`, which fails, because the URL in the microservice is not `/auth/lorem/ipsum` but `/lorem/ipsum`.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: auth
          uri: 'http://localhost:8071'
          predicates:
            - Path=/auth/**
```

Is there a way to define a path for each microservice or do I have to set `server.servlet.context-path` for each microservice to achieve what I would like to do?

Spring boot version: 2.6.1 & Spring cloud version: 2021.0.0

Comment: You have to manipulate the path with a filter. In your case StripPrefix=1 will work

Comment: Thank you, @spencergibb. l feel like l didn't do enough research to figure this out...